# Use ClassName::new (java 8) to generate a class instance failed

Tags: intellij-idea, lambda, java-8, lombok, method-reference

The context is:

- IDE: intellij
- Use Lombok @Data @AllArgsConstructor to annotate my model class
- Compile is OK, but run following case failed.

  ```
  /** This is the model class */
  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  class Message {
     public Long id;
     public String name;
  }

  /** This is a test case */
  @Test
  public void testConstructRef() {
      BiFunction<Long, String, Message> constructFunc = Message::new;
      Message msg = constructFunc.apply(1L, "this is a message");

      assertEquals(1L, (long) msg.getId());
      assertEquals("this is a message", msg.getName());
  }
  ```

From IDE, the `Message` constructor & getter/setter are all there. **Compile is OK, but run failed**.

So my question is:

- Is it a Intellij issue OR lombok issue OR java 8 issue?
- Anyone encountered this before? how to fix it if i have to use lombok? (if i write constructor/getter/setter manually, it can run successfully.)

---

BTW, the running error is:

```
    Error:(40, 63) java: incompatible types: invalid constructor reference
        constructor Message in class java8.methodref.TestDemo.Message cannot be applied to given types
          required: no arguments
          found: java.lang.Long,java.lang.String
          reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    Error:(43, 40) java: cannot find symbol
      symbol:   method getId()
      location: variable msg of type java8.methodref.TestDemo.Message
    Error:(44, 50) java: cannot find symbol
      symbol:   method getName()
      location: variable msg of type java8.methodref.TestDemo.Message
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error:(40, 63) java: incompatible types: invalid constructor reference
    constructor Message in class java8.methodref.TestDemo.Message cannot be applied to given types
      required: no arguments
      found: java.lang.Long,java.lang.String
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Error:(43, 40) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getId()
  location: variable msg of type java8.methodref.TestDemo.Message
Error:(44, 50) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getName()
  location: variable msg of type java8.methodref.TestDemo.Message

Comment: Works flawlessly for me. 

"IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3
Build #IU-163.7743.44, built on November 17, 2016

JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b2 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
"

Comment: @pivovarit I'll try it with your env params. What's your lombok version? (mine is: lombok-1.16.8.jar)

Comment: @JasonS 1.16.10 I included the full answer for clarity

Comment: You have the lombok plugin for IntelliJ? Are you running the test from the commandline or from IntelliJ? It looks like Lombok didn't get a chance to generate the 2 arg constructor when the test runs, if you run from within the IDE the plugin might be causing issues.

Comment: Also, I've had a couple of issues with the Lombok plugin, e.g. by using key combo's to move annotations such as `@AllArgsConstructor`. For some of them, the only fix is to restart IntellJ (not kidding, for example https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/270)

Comment: Yes, i have installed the lombok plugin. Use ctrl + F12, i can see the generated constructor and methods. And also compile is OK. Only running does not

Comment: Did you enable the annotation preprocessors in IntelliJ for your project? Code works perfect here too.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I re-created a maven project and move the code. And it works. I suspect that there must be something wrong with my environment.

Comment: Did you try a re-start of IntelliJ? Sometimes the Lombok plugin looses track and restarting is the only way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works flawlessly with the setup:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.16.10</version>
</dependency>
```

> "IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 Build #IU-163.7743.44, built on November 17,
>   2016 JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b2 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
>   by JetBrains s.r.o "